# Angular 2 keyframe animation with properties with hyphens

Tags: angular

I am trying to re-create this animation on my component: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/source/zooming_exits/zoomOutUp.css

I can't find any examples of using easing on keyframes.  The only easing example I can see is for a single step and it works by passing in a string instead of a number for the animation duration i.e `animate(1s 1s ease)`.

What is the proper way to add in properties that have hyphens in them and do easing with keyframes?

The docs only has a few properties so I am not even sure if this is doing it the right way but it appears to work but I think it might not actually using the easing and transform origin specified.

This is what I tried:

```
transition('* => unloaded', [
    animate(1000, keyframes([
        style({
            opacity: 1,
            transform: 'scale3d(.475, .475, .475) translate3d(0, 60px, 0)',
           'animation-timing-function': 'cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190)',
            offset: 0.4
        }),
        style({
            opacity: 0,
            transform: 'scale3d(.1, .1, .1) translate3d(0, -2000px, 0)',
            'transform-origin': 'center bottom',
            'animation-timing-function': 'cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1)',
            offset: 1
        })
    ]))
])
```

It works but it doesn't look like the animate.css animation.  I don't think it's taking all settings.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to write the style properties in camel case? For example "transform-origin" as transformOrigin? JavaScript uses this form since names of variables cannot contain hyphens. But I'm just guessing, I don't have experience with the animation API.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that they just don't support this yet.

Comment: Your example works just fine and the Animation API does support what you wanna do as you can see here https://gfycat.com/ValuablePoliticalAmazondolphin You need to add a fixed width to your host component ```:host {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 38rem;
}```

Comment: @WassimChegham Using camel case makes no difference.  I am looking in inspector and it does not take the transform-origin or timing fuction.  I can't see how giving a fixed size to the :host is relevant.  The problem as far as i can see it is the Angular 2 animation api doesnt support these properties or if it does it wraps them in an undocumented way

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, instead of hyphens you will use camel case (ie: transformOrigin) as this is what JavaScript understands.

Additionally, it sounds like you need to utilize states to achieve your desired easing animation effects. After you define states, you can define transitions between the states. Each transition controls the timing of switching between one set of styles and the next:

```
transition('inactive => active',
animate('100ms ease-in')),
transition('active => inactive',
animate('100ms ease-out'))
```

Take a look at the [Angular2 Animation Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#example-transitioning-between-states) as it goes into great detail on this.

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post; the documentation says how to use easing on a single transition.  It does not say how to do it with keyframes.  Your answer also does not address my question which is about keyframes.  Also camel case seems to have no effect on timing properties.